# Append tr but don't append if already added in tr

Tags: jquery, append, html-table

```js
var data = [{
  "org_name": "General",
  "suborg_name": "General1"
}, {
  "org_name": "General",
  "suborg_name": "General2"
}, {
  "org_name": "General",
  "suborg_name": "General3"
}, {
  "org_name": "Fund",
  "suborg_name": "Fund1"
}, {
  "org_name": "Fund",
  "suborg_name": "Fund2"
}, {
  "org_name": "Fund",
  "suborg_name": "Fund3"
}]


var tr;
$.each(data, function(i, v) {
  tr = $('<tr class="org_name"/>');
  tr.append("<td id=''>" + v.org_name + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td id=''>" + v.suborg_name + "</td>");

  $("table").append(tr);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
</table>
```

The output I want is:

```
General General1
        General2
        General3
Fund    Fund1
        Fund2
        Fund3
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Its better to have  data like,`var data = [{
  "org_name": "General",
  "suborg_name": ["General1","General2","General3"]
}, {
  "org_name": "Fund",
  "suborg_name": ["Fund1","Fund2","Fund3"]
}];`

Comment: @RohanKumar i think it is also i great idea i will look into it if i cant create that format of json. I am doing my own format of json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply build yourself a check in the loop. Maybe with another array/object to compare with.

```js
var data = [{
  "org_name": "General",
  "suborg_name": "General1"
}, {
  "org_name": "General",
  "suborg_name": "General2"
}, {
  "org_name": "General",
  "suborg_name": "General3"
}, {
  "org_name": "Fund",
  "suborg_name": "Fund1"
}, {
  "org_name": "Fund",
  "suborg_name": "Fund2"
}, {
  "org_name": "Fund",
  "suborg_name": "Fund3"
}];

var added = [];

$.each(data, function(i, v) {
  var name = "&nbsp;";

  if( added.indexOf(v.org_name) == -1 ) {
      name = v.org_name;
      added.push(v.org_name);
  }
  
  var tr = $('<tr class="org_name"/>');
  tr.append("<td id=''>" + name + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td id=''>" + v.suborg_name + "</td>");

  $("table").append(tr);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
</table>
```

Comment: simple to understand. give me 4 minutes to accept :)

Comment: but this would fail if org_name are not in ordered way. Like, General1, General2, Fund1, General3 ... then output would be `General General1
        General2
Fund    Fund1
        Fund2        General3
        Fund3`

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar i didnt thought of it let me  check

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar i think it will not happened since the format is already fix

Comment: @BrownmanRevival, then in that case this is the perfect solution. cheers !!

Answer (score 1):

check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qzfv5kq2/) here

```
var tr;
var orgName=' ';
$.each(data, function(i, v) {
    if(orgName!=v.org_name){
  tr = $('<tr class="org_name"/>');
    tr.append("<td id=''>" + v.org_name + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td id=''>" + v.suborg_name + "</td>");
}else{
  tr = $('<tr class="org_name"/>');
    tr.append("<td id=''> </td>");
    tr.append("<td id=''>" + v.suborg_name + "</td>");
}
orgName = v.org_name;
  $("table").append(tr);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Find if existing tr with org name exist. If exist then put empty string in first td and append after same org tr. if not, then add org name in first td and append to table.

```js
var data = [{
      "org_name": "General",
      "suborg_name": "General1"
    }, {
      "org_name": "General",
      "suborg_name": "General2"
    }, {
      "org_name": "General",
      "suborg_name": "General3"
    }, {
      "org_name": "Fund",
      "suborg_name": "Fund1"
    }, {
      "org_name": "Fund",
      "suborg_name": "Fund2"
    }, {
      "org_name": "Fund",
      "suborg_name": "Fund3"
    }]


    var tr;

    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
      
      var rowExist = $('table').find('tr.' + v.org_name).length;
      tr = $('<tr class="org_name ' + v.org_name + '"/>');
      var orgName = '';
      if (rowExist == 0)
      {
        orgName = v.org_name;
        $('table').append(tr);
      }
      else 
      {
        $('table').find('tr.' + v.org_name).last().after(tr);
      }
      tr.append("<td id=''>" + orgName  + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td id=''>" + v.suborg_name + "</td>");  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
</table>
```